# how to match single pattern and replace it with multiple pattern in perl

Tags: perl

i have one file which contain following info - 
input -

```
a[1]= something_data_1;
a[2]= something_data_2;
a[3]= something_data_3;
```

so i want to replace that "a" with different pattern like below,
Here diff* is a string which I want to replace.

Output -

```
diff1 [1]= something_data_1;
diff2 [1]= something_data_1;
diff3 [1]= something_data_1;

diff1 [2]= something_data_2;
diff2 [2]= something_data_2;
diff3 [2]= something_data_2;
```

.....

I have tried:

```
/usr/bin/perl -w

open(FH,'<',$file_name);
 foreach(<FH>)
  {
    if(/a(\[.*)/)
    {
      $_= "diff1$1 ". "diff2$1";
    }
  }
```

after trying this i am getting output like this,

diff[1] = diff2 something_data;

i am not able to understand what to do

Comment: You do realize that once you replaced the "a" with "diff1" that there's no longer an "a" to replace with "diff2"?

Comment: Can you describe your desired transformation with some English phrases, instead of just code? Why wouldn't a static output of those 3 strings be sufficient?

Comment: yes jeff  you are right once i replaced that a with diff1 there is no longer a to replace , is there any counter solution to get desired output mentioned above

Comment: Does your input file have DOS-style line endings?

Comment: its unix -style ending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want something like

```
chomp(my $line = $_);
if ($line eq "a") {
    $_ = "diff1\ndiff2\ndiff3\n";
}
```

---

I'm assuming you haven't `chomp`ed so that `$_` still 3nds with newline. You need to capture the text that follows "a" so you can reuse it:

```
if (/^(\s*)a(\[.*)/) {
    $_ = "${1}diff1$2".
         "${1}diff2$2".
         "${1}diff3$2;
}
```

Comment: Hi glenn can you please help for edited question,thanks in advance.

Comment: hi glen , using your solution i am getting output something like this, diff1[1] =diff[2] = something;